# Create multiple incrementing columns using with recursive in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I'm trying to create a table with the following columns:

[image]

I want to use a with recursive table to do this. The following code however is giving the following error:

> 'ERROR: column "b" does not exist'

```
WITH recursive numbers AS 
( 
  SELECT 1,2,4 AS a, b, c 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a+1, b+1, c+1 
  FROM Numbers 
  WHERE a + 1 <= 10 
) 
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

I'm stuck because when I just include one column this works perfectly. Why is there an error for multiple columns?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a simple syntax issue: You are aliasing the columns incorrectly. (`SELECT 1,2,4 AS a, b, c`) is incorrect.  Your attempt has 5 columns: `1,2,a,b,c`

Break it down to just: `Select 1,2,4 as a,b,c` and you see the error but `Select 1 a,2 b,4 c` works fine.

b is unknown in the base select because it is being interpreted as a field name; yet no table exists having that field.  Additionally the union would fail as you have 5 fields in the base and 3 in the recursive union.

DEMO: http://rextester.com/IUWJ67486

One can define the columns outside the select making it easier to manage or change names.

```
WITH recursive numbers (a,b,c) AS 
( 
  SELECT 1,2,4 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a+1, b+1, c+1 
  FROM Numbers 
  WHERE a + 1 <= 10 
) 
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

or this approach which aliases the fields internally so the 1st select column's names would be used. (a,b,c)  vs somereallylongalias... in union query.  It should be noted that not only the name of the column originates from the 1st query in the unioned sets; but also the datatype for the column; which, must match between the two queries.

```
WITH recursive numbers  AS 
( 
  SELECT 1 as a ,2 as b,4  as c
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a+1 someReallyLongAlias
       , b+1 someReallyLongAliasAgain
       , c+1 someReallyLongAliasYetAgain
  FROM Numbers 
  WHERE a<5
) 
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

Lastly, If you truly want to stop at 5 then the where clause should be `WHERE a < 5`.  The image depicts this whereas the query does not; so not sure what your end game is here.